# Manual Route Adjustment Using Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps

In Google Maps for the web, it is possible to manually adjust an automatically created route by dragging a point on the path to any other road in view.  The Android app does not have this feature built-in.  Is it possible to manually adjust routes in an application that uses the com.google.android.maps API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

com.google.android.maps does not offer routing at all, let alone automated routing, let alone manual adjustments to automated routing.

If you are drawing your own routes using an overlay, you can respond to touch events in the overlay and adjust your route however you wish.